Ipsec on ubuntu tunnel is up, however routes not created thus not routing traffic
Good day everyone.
I am hoping this post finds everyone well.
I am trying to get some help as after reading posts and KB's for 2 days, and trying multiple suggestions, I am simply not coming right.
In the past I have done hundreds of ipsec vpn's using openswan on ubuntu without any issues.
I am trying to now setup a new vpn server for a client as the B party is upgrading and the new ciphers are no longer supported by openswan.
Current setup :
VPN server running ubuntu 24.04 , strongswan installed.
Few servers that need to connect via this vpn to B-party, all located in the cloud including the vpn server. Thus all of them have private IPs with the vpn server also having a static public ip.
We have configured the ipsec.conf file and managed to get phase1 up and the tunnel established.
Routes have been added on the cloud to route destination traffic through the vpn server.
VPN server has been enabled on the console as well as on OS level to allow traffic forwarding.
The Issue:
When we try to connect from one of the servers in the subnet specified, it does not reach the endpoint and B-party is not seeing any traffic.
After investigations, I found with tcpdump that the vpn server does not seem to be routing the traffic via the vpn tunnel, however I can see it receiving the traffic and trying to send it directly over the internet.
I have checked the ip -s xfrm output which usually shows the routes created by ipsec, however, it seems that no routes are being created which I suspect is in fact why it is not routing over the tunnel.
Some suggestions have been regarding the iptables rules, however all these have been added as per below :
*nat
-I POSTROUTING 1 -m policy --pol ipsec --dir out -j ACCEPT
-A POSTROUTING -s a.a.a.0/16 -o ens4 -m policy --pol ipsec --dir out -j ACCEPT
-A POSTROUTING -s a.a.a.0/16 -o ens4 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT

*mangle
-A FORWARD --match policy --pol ipsec --dir in -s a.a.a.0/16 -o ens4 -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags SYN,RST SYN -m tcpmss --mss 1361:1536 -j TCPMSS --set-mss 1360
COMMIT
# Don't delete these required lines, otherwise there will be errors
*filter
:ufw-before-input - [0:0]
:ufw-before-output - [0:0]
:ufw-before-forward - [0:0]
:ufw-not-local - [0:0]
# End required lines
-A ufw-before-forward --match policy --pol ipsec --dir in --proto esp -s a.a.a.0/16 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-forward --match policy --pol ipsec --dir out --proto esp -d a.a.a.0/16 -j ACCEPT

IPsec statusall :
ipsec statusall
Status of IKE charon daemon (strongSwan 5.9.5, Linux 6.8.0-1014-gcp, x86_64):
  uptime: 28 minutes, since Sep 13 09:20:09 2024
  malloc: sbrk 3264512, mmap 0, used 1343456, free 1921056
  worker threads: 11 of 16 idle, 5/0/0/0 working, job queue: 0/0/0/0, scheduled: 3
  loaded plugins: charon aesni aes rc2 sha2 sha1 md5 mgf1 random nonce x509 revocation constraints pubkey pkcs1 pkcs7 pkcs8 pkcs12 pgp dnskey sshkey pem openssl fips-prf gmp agent xcbc hmac gcm drbg attr kernel-netlink resolve socket-default connmark stroke vici updown eap-mschapv2 xauth-generic counters
Listening IP addresses:
  a.a.a.54
Connections:
   ikev2-vpn:  a.a.a.54...<b-prty-ip>  IKEv2
   ikev2-vpn:   local:  [vpn-router-public] uses pre-shared key authentication
   ikev2-vpn:   remote: [<b-prty-ip>] uses pre-shared key authentication
   ikev2-vpn:   child:  a.a.a.6/32 a.a.a.2/32 a.a.a.3/32 a.a.a.4/32 a.a.a.5/32 === x.x.x.x/32 y.y.y.y TUNNEL
Security Associations (1 up, 0 connecting):
   ikev2-vpn[1]: ESTABLISHED 28 minutes ago, a.a.a.54[vpn-router-public]...<b-prty-ip>[<b-prty-ip>]
   ikev2-vpn[1]: IKEv2 SPIs: db781b4ff41c024f_i* bbfcfb3caa539316_r, pre-shared key reauthentication in 23 hours
   ikev2-vpn[1]: IKE proposal: AES_CBC_256/HMAC_SHA2_256_128/PRF_HMAC_SHA2_256/MODP_2048

ipsec.conf file :
config setup
    charondebug="all"
    #uniqueids=yes
    #strictcrlpolicy=no

conn ikev2-vpn
    auto=start
    #auto=route
    authby=secret
    compress=no
    type=tunnel
    keyexchange=ikev2
    ike=aes256-sha256-modp2048
    installpolicy=yes
    esp=aes256-sha256
    ikelifetime=86400s
    lifetime=43200s
    fragmentation=yes
    forceencaps=yes
    #dpdaction=clear
    #dpddelay=300s
    left=a.a.a.54
    leftid=vpn-router-public
    #leftcert=server-cert.pem
    #leftsendcert=always
    leftsubnet=a.a.a.6/32,a.a.a.2/32,a.a.a.3/32,a.a.a.4/32,a.a.a.5/32
    right=<b-prty-ip>
    rightid=<b-prty-ip>
    rightsubnet=x.x.x.x/32,y.y.y.y/32

Please let me know what other information you need from me to assist as I am out of ideas at the moment.
